# ViewModel to handle multiple data models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am batting 1000 here with my questions. So i will try to be as descriptive as possible.

I have multiple views in a layout that come from different models. 
 When a record is selected from a list it opens this layout. At the top of the layout it displays the record information in a table format. This is a simple ID - /AuditSchedule/1122. This is currently the Body. This works.

In another area of the layout i have a list of action links (side menu) that are generated from a another table. The links, I think should be as follows but not sure /AuditSchedule/1122/1. This was accomplished by using the Global.asax with routes.

Naturally when you open this layout you should get all the above plus the first record of the next area of the layout which is the form. In this form i need it to show a question from a table of questions and have a set of check boxes created with, what i will call scores, to the right of the question. These scores are also in a table called scores. Everything that i have in this is pretty much in a data table so that everything can be edited and changed if needed.

When a user submits the form it will store in another table called MainAnswers the id's of the auditSchedule, mainQuestion, and a string of the score. This table is a blank table so it would insert a new record for every Main Question for that AuditSchedule.

So far i have had no luck with help on this. If anyone could point me to an example of this that they have seen. It would be great. I cannot be the only one that has tried to do this. However i am new to MVC C#. If this were Zend and PHP i would have no issues.

I have used the code first approach. All of my relationships are done. The issue lies in implementing the view and saving the information in the right tables.

Anyone that can help would be much appreciated. I am struggling here.

Updated 08/16/2012 3:12pm

Let me take baby steps first.

I want to be able to select a menu Item from the side and have a list of questions come up from that section. Here is my Code:

```
@{ Layout = null; }
@model QQAForm.ViewModels.AuditFormEdit

<table width="698" border="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td align="center"><b>Section</b><br />1.0</td>
<td>

<br />(Title of Section Goes Here - SubcategoryName - Located in Subcategory Model)<br />


<br />

(Child Questions Go here - QuestionText - Located in ChildQuestion Model)

</td>
<td>
        (This should be the result of what is written in AuditFormEdit view model - it does not currently work - Nothing shows up)
        @for (int index = 0; index < Model.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Count; index++)
        {

            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].Checked)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index], Model.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].ScoreName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].ScoreID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList[index].ScoreName)


        }

   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the View model i am working on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using QQAForm.Models;

namespace QQAForm.ViewModels
{
public class AuditFormEdit
{
    public List<SubcategoryHelper> SubcategoryHelperGet { get; set; }

    public class SubcategoryHelper : Models.SubCategory
    {
        public SubcategoryHelper(Models.SubCategory subCat)
        {
            this.SubCategoryID = subCat.SubCategoryID;
            this.SubcategoryName = subCat.SubcategoryName;
        }

    }


    public Models.MainAnswer ScoreInstance { get; set; }

    public List<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper> ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList { get; set; }

    public void InitializeScoreCheckBoxHelperList(List<Models.Score> ScoreList)
    {
        if (this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList == null)
            this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList = new List<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper>();

        if (ScoreList != null
            && this.ScoreInstance != null)
        {
            this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Clear();
            ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper scoreCardCheckBoxHelper;
            string scoreTypes =
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ScoreInstance.Score) ?
                string.Empty : this.ScoreInstance.Score;
            foreach (Models.Score scoreType in ScoreList)
            {
                scoreCardCheckBoxHelper = new ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper(scoreType);
                if (scoreTypes.Contains(scoreType.ScoreName))
                    scoreCardCheckBoxHelper.Checked = true;
                this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Add(scoreCardCheckBoxHelper);
            }
        }
    }


    public void PopulateCheckBoxsToScores()
    {
        this.ScoreInstance.Score = string.Empty;
        var scoreType = this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList.Where(x => x.Checked)
                              .Select<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper, string>(x => x.ScoreName)
                              .AsEnumerable();
        this.ScoreInstance.Score = string.Join(", ", scoreType);
    }


    public class ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper : Models.Score
    {
        public bool Checked { get; set; }

        public ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper() : base() { }

        public ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper(Models.Score score)
        {
            this.ScoreID = score.ScoreID;
            this.ScoreName = score.ScoreName;
        }
    }



}
}
```

Here is the controller parts:

```
    //get
    public ActionResult _Forms(int section)
    {
        AuditFormEdit viewModel = new AuditFormEdit();
        //viewModel.ScoreInstance = _db.MainAnswers.Single(r => r.MainAnswerID == id);
        _db.SubCategories.Single(r => r.SubCategoryID == section);
        viewModel.InitializeScoreCheckBoxHelperList(_db.Scores.ToList());
        return View(viewModel);
    }



    //post
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _Forms(AuditFormEdit viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.PopulateCheckBoxsToScores();
            _db.Entry(viewModel.ScoreInstance).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("/");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

So if you look at the Layout, where it show the spot for _Forms the Section should change with the link /AuditSchedule/1132/1 - it does not. As well as my check boxes which currently do not show up either.

Answer (score 0):

> ...my check boxes which currently do not show up either.

That's because the line which sets the `viewModel.ScoreInstance` in your controller's GET action is commented out:

```
//viewModel.ScoreInstance = _db.MainAnswers.Single(r => r.MainAnswerID == id);
```

Hence `viewModel.ScoreInstance` is `null` and in `InitializeScoreCheckBoxHelperList` you fill the `ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList` only when `viewModel.ScoreInstance` is **not** `null`:

```
if (this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList == null)
    this.ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList = new List<ScoreCardCheckBoxHelper>();

if (ScoreList != null
    && this.ScoreInstance != null)
{
    //... add elements to ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList
}
```

Empty `ScoreCardCheckBoxHelperList` = no checkboxes.